# 2D Shape drawing

Tags: c++, shapes

I want to draw 2D shapes in C++, probably not more advanced than rectangles!

I'm looking for a C++ API that will be simple and easy to use, as I don't need many advanced features such as image mapping etc.

I've read about cairographics.org Cairo and it looks very good. Before I start with it, would you recommend a possible alternative, or improvement on Cairo? I'm developing on Windows in VS 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.sfml-dev.org/

Comment: Thank you. Looks like sfml will do the job.